# Springboot Failed to configure a DataSource : 'url' but I'm not using database

Tags: java, spring, maven, jackson

I'm building a Springboot application that will read data from the json file but I'm getting this error:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.visma</groupId>
    <artifactId>assigment</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>assigment</name>
    <description></description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm just building a project as part of college assigment.
Do I need to set up the driver?
If I need to what suitable driver will be suitable for only reading and writing json file?

Comment: Add your configuration file, please.

Comment: @M.Dudek You mean application.proeprties file? I'm new to Spring Boot.

Comment: `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` depending on which tool you are using

Comment: Probably you used some of @Enable... spring annotations? If yes, which exactly?

Comment: @M.Dudek added pom.xml file.

Comment: @SergeyVasnev I didn't add any annotations that starts with Enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try disable autoconfiguration for the datasource and also JPA:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

In addition, if you don't want using database in your application, you can remove JPA dependency in your `pom.xml`. Just remove:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```